# Different ways of obtaining string representation of object

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript class `Data` in which I tried to get the string representation of my object:

```
function Data(t, s, m) {    
    this.time = t;
    this.sender = s;
    this.message = m;    
    var stringRep = function() {
        return ("time:" + this.time + " sender:" + this.sender + " message:" + this.message)

    };
    console.log(this.stringRep); //returns undefined    
    var typeRep = (jQuery.type(1234));
    console.log(this.typeRep); //returns undefined

    Data.prototype.toString = function DataToString() {
        var ret = "time:" + this.time + " sender:" + this.sender + " message:"
                + this.message;
        return ret;
    }
    console.log(this.toString()); //returns correct toString representation
}
```

First I tried using `stringRep` which gave `undefined`. Then I even tried to get the type of simple no. 1234 using `typeRep` which also returned `undefined`. Then finally I got help from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) to correctly override `toString` method.

What was wrong in previous approaches?

Comment: `this.stringRep` is undefined becaus you just declared `var stringRep`; same goes for `this.typeRep`;

Comment: Why would the local variables `stringRep` and `typeRep` be members of `this`, or of any object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made two mistakes :

- You defined `stringRep` as a private variable, and tried to called it
  by doing `this.stringRep`. You need to define it as a property of
  Data's instances by doing `this.stringRep = function(){ //...}`
- `stringRep` is a function, you need to do  `this.stringRep()` to
  execute it.

And by the way, you should avoid overwriting the `toString()` method.

EDIT : To be more specific : personally, I think it could be confusing for developers, because they might think they are using the *native* JavaScript method, but if you don't think so, there's no problem.

Comment: "avoid overwriting the toString() method" Why? There's nothing wrong with doing that.

Comment: Because you might need to execute the *native* `toString()` method for debugging purposes, plus it could confuse the users, who might (I would) think they're executing the native `toString()` method.

Comment: Why would anyone be expecting to get `[object Object]`? If they are, so they can check if it's *really* an object, they can do `Object.prototype.toString.call(data)` where `data` is an instance of the overwritten object. That's how frameworks like Underscore do it.

Comment: They would expect it... because it's what the native method would give them ? On the contrary getting something different than that *will* confuse them.
And you're missing the point, I know how some frameworks do type detection. If you want to create your own frameworks and use method names which are already native JS methods, fine. I was just warning the OP that it might confuse developers.

Comment: @WaldoJeffers thanks for pointing out the 2 mistakes. But I also disagree on your opinion of avoiding the overriding of `toString()` method.

Comment: If you know what you are aware of what you're doing, then you're absolutely fine. I'll edit my answer a bit.

Comment: But I'm asking you *why* a user would expect to get the native `toString` method. To avoid extended discussion here, [I've created a chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58970/tostring-overwriting-discussion) if you're interested in discussing further.

Answer (score 2):

You're dealing with a scoping problem. First off, your `stringRep` function isn't defined as a property of `Data`, merely as a variable. What you want to do is this:

```
function Data(t, s, m) {
    this.stringRep = function() {
        // Your definition goes here
    };

    // Now you can call it like so
    console.log(this.stringRep());
};
```

As for your `toString`, you're overwriting it correctly but if you do that in the constructor, it'll be recreated every time you generate a new `Data` instance. Instead, try this:

```
function Data(t, s, m) {
    // All of your code except for toString
};

Data.prototype.toString = function() {
    var ret = "time:" + this.time + " sender:" + this.sender + " message:"
            + this.message;
    return ret;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You created 2 local variables by using var stringRep and var typeRep, but then tried to log them as fields of the Data class by using this.stringRep and this.typeRep, either replace the two "var " keywords with "this." or remove the two "this." in the log commands.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, both `stringRep` and `typeRef` are defined as private variables but you're trying to use them as fields. So you should ideally define the two variables with `this.` prefix, or simply refrain from invoking the two variables with the `this.` prefix.